# C# generic type with obligatory property

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, generic-type-parameters

I'm building a universal CRUD for MongoDB handling and I'm having trouble with generic type . Issue is that I need to use a property of the type but generic type doesn't have this by default.

```
public static Task UpdateConfig<T>(T config)
{
    IMongoCollection<T> collection = ConnectToMongo<T>("collectionName", "dataBase");
    FilterDefinition<T>? filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", config.Id);
    return collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, config, new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true });
}
```

Problem lies in the line:

```
FilterDefinition<T>? filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", config.Id);
```

The config doesn't come with Id property but it is essential that this property is used. Can anyone help out with this?

Comment: Why not defining an interface that has an Id property with a Getter, and then define constraint on T that it implements this interface ?

public class SomeClass<T> where T : ISomeInterface
{
 public int Id { get; }
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
 public int Id { get; } 
}

Comment: You could use a separate base class or interface, e.g. IEntity, which has a getter for your Id, and have your classes implement it. Then you can specify the generic type and limit it: `where T: IEntity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to handle requirements like this in dot net is to use generic constraints and an interface:

```cs
public interface IConfig // You might want to change this name
{
   int Id {get;} // data type assumed to be int, can be anything you need of course
}

....

public static Task UpdateConfig<T>(T config) where T : IConfig
... rest of the code here
```

Comment: Hey, that's close to a solution but now I get an error on invoking the method
When I do 
UpdateConfig<MyModel>(model)
I get the myModel cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UpdateConfig<T>(T)'

Comment: You must invoke the method with an argument that implements the interface.... What error do yo get?

Comment: Edited the above message. Also the error states that:
There is no implicit reference conversion from MyModel' to 'IConfig'

Comment: That's what I said, your `MyModel` class must implement the `IConfig` interface. It's not enough that it has the `Id` property - it should be declared as `class MyModel : IConfig` (at the very least).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so very much!  Man, I love C# but there is still so much to learn for me.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code here:

```
public interface IId {
   public int Id {get;set;}
}

public static Task UpdateConfig<T>(T config) where T : IId
    {
        IMongoCollection<T> collection = ConnectToMongo<T>("collectionName", "dataBase");
        FilterDefinition<T>? filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", config.Id);
        return collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, config, new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true });
    }
```

This should work ish? Unless I totally screwed up the where syntax...